# Magento customer registration error

Tags: php, magento

I installed a multi vendor module on magento and when you try to register you get this error;

```
Cannot save the customer.`Invalid method Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::cleanPasswordsValidationData(Array ( ) )`
```

help will be much appreciated

Comment: so you expect us to solve this issue without seeing a single line of code ? :)

Answer (score 0):

it was a form validation issue, you need to assign your magento version in accountcontroller.php of the module. Mine was 1.9.1.0 but the former value was 1.8.1. you search for this line of code and change the version

```
    if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(),"1.9.1.0",">="))
{
    // Only from 1.9.1.0
    $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
}
```